# d3.select("#element") not working when code above the html element

Tags: d3.js

This works:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg");</script>
```

This doesn't:

```
<script>var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg");</script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

I tried wrapping the code in a jquery document.ready(), grabbing the element with jquery, and passing it into d3.select, but that didn't work either. **Edit** Once I got the jquery document.ready() syntax right, it worked.

Any way I can include the javascript at the top of the page and still select an element below? Thanks.

Comment: Easy solution but a tricky one as one could easily forget. As written by the most up voted solution. Be careful about playing with dom elements before they are being created. In other words before they exist in dorm hierarchy. So load the script after the element by the name of char ID.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
<script>$(function(){var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg");});</script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

In other words, it's not happening because you can't query against something that doesn't exist yet-- so just do it after the page loads (here via jquery).

Btw, its recommended that you place your JS files before the close of your body tag.

Comment: I tried jquery as well `d3.select($("#chart"))`, but that didn't work either. Despite the D3 docs stating: `These methods can also accept nodes, which is useful for integration with third-party libraries such as jQuery or developer tools`

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my post-- which is you're trying to query against something that doesnt exist yet. Think about it-- as the page loads into the browser its executing the code. If your JS is before the element its trying to query, its executing while that node does not exist-- understand? You NEED to wait until the DOM is fully loaded (or the node you're working with is fully loaded) in order to query it.

Comment: Rick Jolly,  d3.select expects a DOM element not a jquery object.  You would want to use $("#chart")[0].  The [0] item is the DOM element reference.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 18):

Not enough reputation to comment yet so I'll just put this here:

To expand on Micah's answer - the browser runs your code top to bottom, so if you write:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg");</script>
```

The browser will create a div with id "chart", and then run your script, which will try to find that div, and, hurray, success.

Otherwise if you write:

```
<script>var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg");</script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

The browser runs your script, and tries to find a div with id chart, but it hasn't been created yet so it fails.

THEN the browser creates a div with id "chart".

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `$(document)` function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

//d3.select('#chart svg')
//d3.select("body").append("svg")


    //var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg");

    var svg = d3.select("#BarChart").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var updateData = function(getData){

    d3.selectAll('svg > g > *').remove();

    d3.csv(getData, function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
      });

      x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
      x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Population");

      var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "state")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

      state.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

      legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

      legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });

    });

}

updateData('data1.csv');

});
```

Comment: what does all this code have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that if your element id is just a `number`, then d3.select("1234"), will not work.

The unique id needs to be an `alpha-numeric` character.

<s>d3.select("1234")</s>

d3.select("container1234")

Answer (score 0):

just add your  `<script src="./custom.js"></script>` before `</bod>` tag. that is supply  time to  `d3.select(#chart)`  detect your `#chart` element in html body

Answer (score 0):

You need to do just simple thing.

- Place/Import your script after `<div></div>` section.
- This is because you D3 script run before loaded the body section, so D3 not able to find out your `div`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this approach. It worked for me.

```
<head> 
<script  type="text/javascript" src='./d3.v4.min.js'></script>
</head> 

<body>
    <div id="jschart41448" style="color:red">
        Hi red
    </div>

    <div id="jschart41449" style="color:blueviolet">
        Hi blueviolet
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript"   >
            d3.select("#jschart41448").style('color', 'green' , null);
            d3.select("#jschart41449").style('color', 'yellow', null);
</script>
</body>
```